# Memsql, set follower on a primary host

Tags: cluster-computing, singlestore

I install memsql on host A to run some functional tests, then I added additional host B using Memsql Ops UI. However, host B does not show on host A Memsql Ops UI. I verified that Memsql Ops is running on host B by connect to port 9000 on host B. I receive this error when running
    memsql-ops follow -h A

```
Failed to connect to primary agent as follower: Agent at A:9000 cannot follow itself
```

Both hosts are running as primary right now.

Comment: Are you running `./memsql-ops follow -h A` on host A? If so, try running from host B. Also, you added your node through the web ui as [shown in this link](http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/setup_onprem/)?

Comment: I am running ./memsql-ops follow -h A on host B, and I have read through that page multiple times.  Haven't found an answer for this so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any chance that the MemSQL Ops install on host B is sharing its data with host A?  For instance, did you copy the data directory from host A to host B when you installed MemSQL Ops on host B (by default, the data directory is in /var/lib/memsql-ops/data)?

MemSQL Ops automatically generates and saves agent IDs when a MemSQL Ops install first starts, which are UUIDs used to distinguish between different MemSQL Ops agents in a cluster. The error you're seeing indicates that you're trying to follow an agent with the same agent ID; one way that this could occur is if you're using the same data directory on both machines.

Comment: That explains it. Host B is actually a clone from Host A with memsql installed. I fix it by running  ./memsql-ops uninstall on host B, go to host A and add host B.